# How do I create a font with semi-bold weight in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, fonts

I wan't to create a semi-bold font in VB.NET.

Why isn't semi-bold available in intellisense?

[screenshot]

I am using .NET 4.5.

Answer (score 2):

```
Label1.Font = New Drawing.Font("Segoe UI Semibold", 10)
```

Add Semibold to font name.

Comment: This works for `"Segoe UI Semibold"` but not for `"Arial Bold"` or `"Segoe UI Bold"`. Why is that?

Comment: I dont know, but if you want use "Bold" just add 3rd parameter to Drawing.Font("Segoe UI", 10, FontStyle.Bold)

Comment: @CrazyTim:     Hahaha!! webx.pl wasn't able to answer your question completely. Segoe UI Semibold is a seperate font. Some fonts have an 'additional' feature of Semibold property. Segoe UI is one of them. Unfortunately, we can do nothing but to wait for semibold versions of fonts like Arial and Century Gothic. :( Lets hope for the best but fast.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simple and is just available in front your eyes.

Just look with care the image you attached and MSDN Document:

System.**Drawing.FontStyle** is **different** from System.**Windows.FontWeights**.

A tip: no big deal, but for conscience' sake and future page visitors, you've cited something about .Net version 4.5... If you click on combo "Other versions", it will show the documentation page in others .Net versions.

So, in this case, System.Windows.FontWeights was introduced by .Net 3.0.

The more correct sentence is: .Net 3.0 (and up) is required to use System.Windows.FontWeights.

Comment: Oh, thank you :). So how does one create a new `System.Drawing.Font` that is semi-bold?

Comment: humm.. as far as i know, I ~think~ you can't. unless your font (ie "Arial") semibold format to new one ("Arial Semibold"), do some importing of your new custom font to your app and set it to your control.

Answer (score 1):

`System.Drawing.Fonts` does not support a SemiBold setting weight.  The [FontWeights](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.fontweights.aspx) is in the System.Windows namespace which is WPF/Silveright - which does support Semi-Bold.  However `System.Drawing.Fonts` is part of Windows Forms which does not.

WPF and Windows Forms use different rendering engines and are not compatible.

Comment: No semi-bold for me :(