# How do I set a different font style than what is offered in the FontStyle enum?

Tags: c#

I am creating PDF documents using SelectPdf. One of these documents needs to use a client-provided font.

The font family in question is Azo Sans, and it contains several different flavors of font such as bold, italic, regular, etc. It also contains styles like "thin". I need to use this thin style, coupled with italics, in my document.

How can I use a style that is not offered in the `FontStyle` enum?

I declare my font as such

```
var font = new Font(font: "Azo Sans", fontSize: 12, fontStyle: FontStyle.Italic | FontStyle.WhatStyleIsUsedHere?);
```

This works for standard styles like bold, underline, etc. How can I combine Italics with the Thin style offered by the Azo Sans font?

Comment: What type is that `Font` type you're using? It doesn't correspond to `SelectPdf`'s `PdfFont` type, nor `System.Drawing.Font`'s type either (as it doesn't have a `String font` ctor parameter... or did you post pseudocode?)

Comment: @Dai Not pseudocode. I am using the `public Font (string familyName, float emSize, System.Drawing.FontStyle style);` constructor from System.Drawing.Font`

Comment: Nope, as long as you use this library you are stuck with what System.Drawing.Font lets you control.  Limited to attributes for TrueType fonts.  You'd be ahead with another library that supports specifying the [weight](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.fontweights?view=windowsdesktop-7.0), as is common in any that supports OpenType.

Comment: @BSO your posted code shows you using a parameter named `fontSize` but the real parameter name is `emSize` - please edit your post to show your **actual** code, not code using fictitious parameters.

Answer (score 0):

- (Disclaimer: I have never used `SelectPdf`, so I cannot verify my answer)
- It looks like `SelectPdf.PdfFont` simply wraps-over GDI's `System.Drawing.Font` *or* specifies from a small collection of Fonts that they *claim* [are "standard" PDF fonts](https://selectpdf.com/docs/T_SelectPdf_PdfStandardFont.htm).

  - Their list includes *Helvetica*, but in-fact, [*Helvetica* hasn't been included with Adobe Acrobat since version 3.0 in the 1990s](https://superuser.com/questions/1615263/force-acrobat-to-use-helvetica-instead-of-arial-like-ghostscript-does).
- However, assuming that it supports all features of `System.Drawing.Font` then you just need to use the same technique for loading arbitrary font-styles and weights (e.g. `Semibold`, `Light`, etc) [which is to specify them in the font-family name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19372577/how-do-i-create-a-font-with-semi-bold-weight-in-vb-net):

  - ...note that doing-so will cause the `Font.Style` property to *incorrectly* return `FontStyle.Regular`, but you can ignore this.

```cs
using System.Drawing;

// ...

PdfDocument pdfDoc = ...

Font font = new Font(
    familyName: "Azo Sans Thin",
    emSize: 12
);

PdfFont pdfFont = pdfDoc.AddFont( font );
```

Comment: @KJ SelectPdf looks like _yet-another_ C#/.NET wrapper over Qt's existing PDF functionality, _especially_ its HTML-to-PDF feature - so I don't want to spend too much time investigating it. I know the Qt library permits it, but it's amazing at just how many nonfree libraries are out there, profiting from Qt's existing work. _le sigh_

Comment: @Dai - I gave this a go, but no luck. While debugging, and attempting to use Azo Sans Thin as the family name, I see that the `Font` being created is defaulting back to Microsoft Sans Serif. I take it this is because Azo Sans Thin is not the actual family, but a style within the Azo Sans font family?

Answer (score 0):

Azo Sans Thin is an Adobe "Licensed" font so I cannot display that, but I here use a similar substitute.

In many apps the light variant can be done via setting the font-weight. Here using SelectPDF online Demo with a Tamil font in upright and inline *`<i>talic`* However the "weight" seems to be ignored even if the family is respected, since using a high value does not show up.

[image]

Here again using the ASP.Net version
[image]

Here is what 400 weight  should look like
[image]

Interesting the Italic is not defined as Italic !!, but then I used `<i>` to slope the upright.
[image]